# MariaDB duplicates being inserted

Tags: python, mariadb

I have the following Python code to check if a MariaDB record exists already, and then inserting. However, I am having duplicates being inserted. Is there something wrong with the code, or is there a better way to do it? I'm new to using Python-MariaDB.

```py
import mysql.connector as mariadb
from hashlib import sha1

mariadb_connection = mariadb.connect(user='root', password='', database='tweets_db')

# The values below are retrieved from Twitter API using Tweepy
# For simplicity, I've provided some sample values
id = '1a23bas'
tweet = 'Clear skies'
longitude = -84.361549
latitude = 34.022003
created_at = '2017-09-27'
collected_at = '2017-09-27'
collection_type = 'stream'
lang = 'us-en'
place_name = 'Roswell'
country_code = 'USA'
cronjob_tag = 'None'
user_id = '23abask'
user_name = 'tsoukalos'
user_geoenabled = 0
user_lang = 'us-en'
user_location = 'Roswell'
user_timezone = 'American/Eastern'
user_verified = 1
tweet_hash = sha1(tweet).hexdigest()

cursor = mariadb_connection.cursor(buffered=True)
cursor.execute("SELECT Count(id) FROM tweets WHERE tweet_hash = %s", (tweet_hash,))
if cursor.fetchone()[0] == 0:
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO tweets(id,tweet,tweet_hash,longitude,latitude,created_at,collected_at,collection_type,lang,place_name,country_code,cronjob_tag,user_id,user_name,user_geoenabled,user_lang,user_location,user_timezone,user_verified) VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)", (id,tweet,tweet_hash,longitude,latitude,created_at,collected_at,collection_type,lang,place_name,country_code,cronjob_tag,user_id,user_name,user_geoenabled,user_lang,user_location,user_timezone,user_verified))
    mariadb_connection.commit()
    cursor.close()
else:
    cursor.close()
    return
```

Below is the code for the table.

```sql
CREATE TABLE tweets (
  id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  tweet VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  tweet_hash VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  longitude FLOAT DEFAULT NULL,
  latitude FLOAT DEFAULT NULL,
  created_at DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
  collected_at DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
  collection_type enum('stream','search') DEFAULT NULL,
  lang VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  place_name VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  country_code VARCHAR(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  cronjob_tag VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  user_id VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  user_name VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  user_geoenabled TINYINT(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  user_lang VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  user_location VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  user_timezone VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  user_verified TINYINT(1) DEFAULT NULL
);
```

Comment: Can we see `SHOW CREATE TABLE mytable` and the actual SQL generated.

Comment: Sure I've updated the question with the actual code snippet and the CREATE TABLE syntax, thanks

Comment: If you are looking for unique tweets, make `tweet` `UNIQUE` or at least `INDEXed`.  The `hash` only adds complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add unique constant to tweet_has filed.

```
alter table tweets  modify tweet_hash varchar(255) UNIQUE ;
```

Comment: I also had to add an exception in the Python code to ignore duplicates insertion errors: `except mariadb.IntegrityError`

Answer (score 1):

Every table should have a `PRIMARY KEY`.  Is `id` supposed to be that?  (The `CREATE TABLE` is not saying so.)  A PK is, by definition, `UNIQUE`, so that would cause an error on inserting a duplicate.

Meanwhile:

- Why have a `tweet_hash`?  Simply index `tweet`.
- Don't say `255` when there are specific limits smaller than that.
- `user_id` and `user_name` should be in another "lookup" table, not both in this table.
- Does `user_verified` belong with the `user`?  Or with each tweet?
- If you are expecting millions of tweets, this table needs to be made smaller and indexed -- else you will run into performance problems.

Comment: Thanks for the good points, here's some of my reasoning and modifications based on your suggestions. 1) `tweet_hash` allows faster look up than actually searching for a full text string with multiple words. 2) I've reduced the `tweet_hash` size to 50, you've rightly pointed out that the sizing of the columns is not optimized. 3) You're right, I should re-structure this to have 2 tables. 4) I do have indexes, but yes, it does need to get smaller

Comment: The randomness of a "hash" makes it no faster.  The overhead of an unnecessary column and index more than counteract any advantage.